# UnknownHostException is being throws when hitting the tmdb api

Tags: android

I am trying to build the movie db app by using retrofit. However I find myself in a confusing state, when I hit the api using Postman I get perfect response, however when I use the API in my app it gives me "Unknownhostexception".
Some help here would be really appreciated.
I referred to some stackoverflow posts saying to put in internet permissions and also to reconnect to wifi , but those have not helped in any-case.
To add on I also tried using the "Fast android networking library" and the result is the same.

Solution :- I restarted my gennymotion emulator and it started working properly .

Comment: what url you are using ?

Comment: you also need permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> have you added this in your mainfest ?

Comment: @HarishKamboj OP writes that this was done.

Comment: @HarishKamboj if the permissions is not written the app fails with another error

Comment: https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=xxxxxxxx
I have removed the api key for now ..

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have an internet connection.Unknownhostexception comes when internet did not work or very slow. Check it into another device.